# Counting input on inputbox Visual Basic

Tags: vba, for-loop, inputbox

Alright so I am quite new with programming and with Visual Basic.
I have these codes, and what I need my program to do is to count the number of input of the user.  Different inputs so I have the inputbox looping and once the user enters the value "0" that's when the looping will stop and a messagebox would show up showing the number of times the inputbox looped (thus showing the number of data entered)

```
Dim inputNumber As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To inputNumber
    inputNumber = InputBox("Please enter a value")
    Do Until inputNumber = "0"
        inputNumber = i
        i = i + 1
    Loop
Next i
MsgBox(i)
```

So it runs but it won't loop and so the messagebox always shows 1

Comment: what is your question

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Well it runs but it won't loop so the message box always says 2.

Answer (score 1):

> show up showing the number of times the inputbox looped

You have the loop incorrect. Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim inputNumber As Long
    Dim i As Long

    inputNumber = 1

    Do Until inputNumber = 0
        inputNumber = Application.InputBox("Please enter a value", Type:=1)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

If you are planning to accept `Text` as well for inputNumber then you will have to change `Dim inputNumber As Long` to `Dim inputNumber As String` and `Type:=1` to `Type:=2`

**Followup from comments**

To show the number of non-zero inputs (**which your question doesn't specify. It says number of loop**), Change the above code to

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim inputNumber As Long
    Dim i As Long

    inputNumber = 1

    Do Until inputNumber = 0
        inputNumber = Application.InputBox("Please enter a value", Type:=1)
        If inputNumber <> 0 Then i = i + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

Comment: The code isn't right, the value of i will be off by 1 if they enter the value 0 the very first time.

Comment: Isn't that correct? `0` is an input to the inputbox? This is what the user said `a messagebox would show up showing the number of times the inputbox looped`

Comment: He wants to show the number of non-zero inputs. You code will be off by one ... pretty sure...

Comment: Maybe you are right but where in the question does he say `show the number of non-zero inputs`. He says `number of times the inputbox looped`

Comment: Yeah it was off by one, if I entered four values, it counts five. But thanks!

Comment: @user3189380: You need to change your question then :)

Comment: I wanted to use zero to stop the looping

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Dim inputNumber as Integer = 0
Dim i as Integer = -1
do
    inputNumber = InputBox("Please enter a value")
    i = i + 1
Loop while inputNumber <> 0
MsgBox("Number of inputs: " & i)
```

Comment: You are right - removed that erroneous "next i". Happy to help.

Comment: @user3189380, if this answers your question, you should mark it as so, both to benefit you and the community.